# What is the line-length limit in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, yaml

I understand that `yamllint` and `ansible-lint` provide warnings when the `line-length` is over the max threshold, which for `yamllint` seems to be a [default of 80](https://yamllint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rules.html#module-yamllint.rules.line_length).

I have seen that some public projects simply edit the rules to increase this limit.

I would like to know why this limit is in place, and when will things start to break in Ansible?

Does anyone have any thoughts on a reasonable limit?

Comment: It's because in the Beginning Of Time&trade;, terminals were 80x25 that is 80 columns and 25 rows high. Some projects believe that all code should fit into a terminal sized to those same standards, and others think that modern 4k monitors have more characters available. It's just "personal preference," and I doubt tehre is any practical limit to the length of a line in yaml short of running out of RAM

Comment: There is not a "real technical" reason for such "short" lines but another one, a biological constrain. It is how the human brain and eyes are working. Trying to explain it here is going instantly out of topic of this site. However, some random entry points for further research: [Line length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_length), [Reading Onscreen: The Effects of Line Length on Performance](https://www.usability.gov/get-involved/blog/2006/08/line-length-and-onscreen-reading.html), etc..

Comment: So in other words, not Ansible will start to break, but the reader, the human in front of the computer will soon not be able to "parse" the lines correctly and start to make errors and mistakes.

Comment: You'll find longer answers and threads on the Stackexchange network under [Ideal column width for paragraphs online](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3618/), [What is the best number of paragraph width for readability?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/108801/).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. This really helps. So without a technical limit, I just need to set a reasonable limit for my project and agree with other project members.
I was mostly worried that Ansible would cut the line off after a certain length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's actually a technical limit, imposed by the [YAML spec](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#example-single-pair-explicit-entry):

> To limit the amount of lookahead required, the “:” indicator must appear at most 1024 Unicode characters beyond the start of the key. In addition, the key is restricted to a single line.

This applies to lines of one of the following forms:

```
<key>: value
<key>:
  <sub-node>
```

`<key>` mustn't be longer than 1024 characters, and mustn't be multiline. While not directly a line limit (as indentation and the following value aren't taken into account), this means that to be safe, you should limit your lines to 1025 characters (key + `:`) so that no illegal key can occur.

While this is the answer to „when will things start to break“, please use a much shorter limit for readability. 80 is a sensible default used by many, ymmv.

Comment: That's interesting, thank you very much. I certainly won't be going anywhere near that limit. I was thinking more of a 180 limit, as I've seen some people do that in public [GitHub Projects](https://github.com/geerlingguy/mac-dev-playbook/blob/master/.yamllint)

Comment: 80 char limit is a vestige of the IBM punch cards used for input back in the 1960s.  It has no place in modern software design.  Today, line length limits should be based on presentation concerns.  As a machine readable format, some limits to ease parser implementations, such as the key length limit described, are what you expect.  yamllint is way off here.

Comment: @CharlieReitzel 80 is used and liked by many people, including me. It is obviously not the one true answer but there's no need to be dismissive about it, and since it's opinion-based, this is not the place to discuss it.

Comment: @flyx If you are comfortable with it, by all means use it.  Didn't mean it like that `:--)`. But setting it as the default value has a wide impact.  For example, when yamllint is used in CI pipelines to lint YAML files, suddenly an entire organization's developers are forced to comply with 1960s punch card limitations!  That doesn't feel reasonable to me.

Comment: @CharlieReitzel It is a widely used value (see e.g. [Prettier](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#print-width), which is far more concerned with imposing a general standard format). Therefore it makes sense as default value. It's quite irrelevant where the value originated from.

Comment: @flyx  Let's agree to disagree. Ime, 80 characters for YAML is way too short and will cause way too many false positives.  I would say the same the same about any source code formatter.  But I won't try to change your mind if you don't try to change mine :--).  All the best.